# How to portforward correctly

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nas, synology

We have a website, and my superiors asked me to install the mail server that is packaged with Synology. As I mess around with port forwarding I was able to set the mail server and the NAS to connect in the internet (meaning I can now access the NAS through internet).

The problem is the website is gone.

How should I fix it? I am using a ZyXEL router and because of my idiocy I cannot remember the default settings in the port forward.

I tried to portforward in port 80, I used in server IP address the public IP that the ISP gave and the default server, I put the IP of our NAS. But when I type the URL of our website it shows the Configuration page of zyxel router. If I portforward the IP address of our NAS in server IP address and used that again in default server address, It shows the Synology site saying "The page you are looking for is not found" Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the webserver?  Is it running from the Synology or another server?  You'll need to find its IP address and forward port 80 to it.

Comment: I would suggest using ports other than 80. You can use 8000 or 8080.

Comment: Thanks Guys I really appreciate it. I will try it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete David Schwartz's comment into a full answer:

Assumption:

- Router
- WebServer (on port 80 and maybe 443 if you have HTTPS pages)
- Synology (5000 or 5001 for the management page, MailStation uses 80 or 443 for HTTPS)

On your router:

- PortForward port 80 to WebServer - This will enable you / your users to connect to your web server by simply typing www.myaddress.com or whatever your URL is.
- PortForward 5000 and/or 5001 to Synology (5000 for HTTP, 5001 for HTTPS - you can change this as needed) - So you can access Synology Web Management from outside world - IF needed (if not, then don't port forward this)
- PortForward 443 to Synology - this will redirect any https request to Synology. Then your client can access the Synology Mailstation by typing --> https://www.myaddress.com/mail

If you do need 443 to go to your WebServer (because you have HTTPS content), then what you can do to work around it:

- PortForward 8080 (or other random port) to Synology port 80
- PortForward 11443 (or other random port) to Synology port 443

Then the way people can access the MailStation is www.myaddress.com:8080/mail or https://www.myaddress.com:11443/mail - not ideal, but it is a workaround.

If you have a 2nd public IP, that will make it so much easier.

Hope this helps, and credit goes to David Schwartz.